# Horizontal gaps in an html email

Tags: gmail, html-email, outlook-2010, gaps-in-visuals

I am trying to fix a problem with an html email where horizontal gaps appear between images that does not exist in the code. I have been on the site and have tried everything anyone has suggested to people who have previously had this problem. I have added display:block, font-size: 0px, lineheight:0px, made sure all padding, margins, and borders were set to 0. I have run out of ideas and was hoping someone can help me. I have outlook 2010 and have tested the email on chrome and explorer for gmail. If you have any suggestions or can help in any way I would really appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv3.jpg) -->
<table style="lineheight:0px; display:block; border-collapse:collapse" width="600" height="814" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  margin="0" border="0" padding="0" align="top">
<tr style="font-size: 0px;"><td style="font-size: 0px;" colspan="3"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/lw56vewpt/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv5_01.jpg" width="600" height="328" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0"></td></tr>
<tr style="font-size: 0px;"><td style="font-size: 0px;" colspan="3"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/sp5jronj5/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv5_02.jpg" width="600" height="251" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0"></td></tr>
<tr style="font-size: 0px;"><td style="font-size: 0px;"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/93h2vhl3x/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv5_03.jpg" width="175" height="107" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0"></td>
<td style="font-size: 0px;"><a href="http://www.dallasbioidenticalhormonedoctor.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/c91olp3q9/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv3_04.jpg" width="253" height="107" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0" alt="link to http://www.dallasbioidenticalhormonedoctor.com/"></a></td>
<td style="font-size: 0px;"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/i11ssudjx/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv5_05.jpg" width="172" height="107" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0"></td></tr>
<tr style="font-size: 0px;"><td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.emtexas.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/7lvmjxgdd/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv3_06.jpg" width="428" height="128" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0" alt="link to http://www.emtexas.com/"></a></td>
<td style="font-size: 0px;"><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/4mtbajw9p/Spring_Back_Into_Action_email_blastv5_07.jpg" width="172" height="128" align="top" style="display:block" margin="0" border="0" padding="0"></td></tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)